# Unique Identifier for Flash Installation

Tags: flash, uniqueidentifier

In a Flash application I would like to obtain the Flash product ID (or any other identifier which would uniquely identify a particular installation of Flash). I haven't found anything in the SDK that provides this? Any ideas?

Terry.
coatta@acm.org

Comment: are you talking about the flash player version?

Answer (score 1):

An

> identifier which would uniquely identify a particular installation of Flash

Would be a privacy risk, aka ‘super-cookie’: like a browser cookie you couldn't refuse or delete.

Some controls (such as Windows Media Player) have had these before, and have had to be fixed. I know of no such thing in the Flash Player, but if there *is* a sneaky way to do it, it's not going to be a deliberate API you can rely on.

You can put an identifier in [Flash Local Storage](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help02.html), which is in effect almost as good because most people don't realise that option exists, so few turn it off. (And if you do, many sites break. And even if you delete the stored values, Flash still locally remembers all the sites you've been to with Flash. It is not a very privacy-conscious plugin.)

Comment: We had been using Local Object Storage previously. But there are some sceanrios (e.g. a Flash application embedded in a PDF document) in which access to LOS has been completely cut-off.

Comment: We don't object to the user refusing the cookie, but with no access to LOS at all, we can't even offer them the choice.